# A memory IC(integrated circuit) consists of a 16-bit address bus and 16-bit data bus lines. What is the size of the memory in bytes?

Tags: memory-management

A memory IC(integrated circuit) consists of a 16-bit address bus and 16-bit data bus lines. What is the size of the memory in bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 16 bit data bus means the memory is organized into 2-byte words. The 16 bit address bus means the IC can address from 0 to 2^16 == 65536 words. So, excluding the non-sensical 0-byte size, the memory size in bytes can be from 2 bytes to 65538*2 == 131072 bytes (128 Kbytes).